# AvailableLetters.remove('a') -not working

Tags: python, list

I am trying to remove element from a list in Python.

```
AvailableLetters = ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z']
AvailableLetters.remove('a')
```

and I am getting the following error

```
AvailableLetters.remove('a')
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, does the lack of commas in your declaration of `AvailableLetters` cause all the letters to be clumped into one item?

Comment: If you don't put commas between strings, python concatenates the strings.  So it is as RedRoboHood presumed, your list has one single string, and thus does not contain the string 'a'.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would vote this down... It's a well formed question by someone who's presumably new to python or just made a silly mistake.

Comment: Where are the commas. The letters will concatenate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
>>> letters.remove('a')
>>> print(letters)
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 6):

> Two or more string literals (i.e. the ones enclosed between quotes) next to each other are automatically concatenated.

```
>>> 'Py' 'thon'
'Python'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your trouble is that python sees 'a' 'b' as 'ab' (probably a C throwback). What you want is:

```
AvailableLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
AvailableLetters.remove('a')
```

Comment: This likely "C throwback" is a useful way of defining long literal strings or (in Python) of defining a string and using different types of quotes around different portions of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate objects in the list with commas, like this:

```
    AvailableLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you confirm your list. You can use `print` to output it.

```
AvailableLetters = ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z']
print AvailableLetters 
# ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
```

I recommend you can take two methods to solve your problem as below:

First method: If you persist in your method, it will just fix bug.

```
AvailableLetters = ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's' 't' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z']
AvailableLetters = list(AvailableLetters[0])
AvailableLetters.remove('a')
print AvailableLetters
# ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Second method: I think it's the best and fastest solution.

```
import string
AvailableLetters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
AvailableLetters.remove('a')
print(AvailableLetters)
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```